# Windows - Run As Different User (on different domain) - Error: "Domain isn't available"

Tags: windows, active-directory, authentication

## Goal

I have a Windows 10 PC.

I want to run an application in the security context of a user on a different Windows domain from the one that my PC is connected to.

## Details

- My PC is connected to DomainABC
- I am connected to a VPN which can reach hosts on DomainXYZ
- I want to run an application locally as `DomainXYZ\Walter`.

## Error

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## Answer using command line.

While writing this question, I found the answer [here](http://www.markwilson.co.uk/blog/2008/03/the-windows-runas-command-and-the-netonly-switch.htm).

The solution is to open `Command Prompt`, and use the `runas` command with the `/netonly` option.

#### Example

`runas /netonly /user:domainXYZ\walter ssms.exe`

Comment: Another solution (in some situations) is open a network connection to the remote host, since if there is an existing network connection Windows will use it.  But this solution is probably more robust.  [Please ignore my deleted comment about trust relationships, I was misunderstanding the scenario.]

Comment: /netonly helped